# what is the best way to visit a particular nodein a link list rather visiting each node?

Tags: data-structures, time, linked-list, time-complexity

what would be a better way to find an item in a list rather visiting each node and comparing  with the key item. 
example:
1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9->10->null. 
In this list, **is there an better way to reach item 6 without visiting each node** form zero to 6.

Comment: Reread one more the book about lists. It will be useful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - with a linked list there is no better option.

There are data structures similar to linked lists which can find the nth item in O(log n), such as skip lists and binary trees. However, in most cases it's a better idea to replace the linked list with a dynamic array.